# Searching in Array of Dictionaries

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm trying to search values in array of dictionaries which I get from JSON. I have a `tableViewController` with `UISearchResultsUpdating`. I found an example with array of Strings:

```
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
    let array = tableData.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And I really don't know how to made search in array like this:

```
(
    {
    id = 3;
    name = TestNewYork;
    },
    {
    id = 2;
    name = TestLA;
    },
    {
    id = 1;
    name = TestWashington;
    }
)
```

my `tableData = []` and `filteredTableData` must be an array too

Please, help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simple filter function to do this...

```
tableData : [[String : String]] = ... // your JSON array of String, String dictionaries...

filteredTableData = tableData.filter{
    dictionary in
    return dictionary["name"] == filterString
}
```

Something like that anyway, not written Swift for a while.

You can wrap it in a function too...

```
func filter(array : [[String : String]], byString filterString : String) -> [[String : String]] {
    return array.filter{
        dictionary in
        return dictionary["name"] == filterString
    }
}
```

Or something. Not checked the code yet. Will be back if it doesn't work.

Checked in Playground and this works...

[image]

**UPDATE**

Changed to this...

```
let data = [
    [
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "a"
    ],
    [
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "b"
    ],
    [
        "id" : 5,
        "name" : "c"
    ]
]

let filteredData = data.filter{
    return $0["name"] == "b"
}
```

And it works. Just can't work out how to wrap in a function.

If you want to match the beginning of words...

```
let data = [
    [
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "Hello"
    ],
    [
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "Goodbye"
    ],
    [
        "id" : 5,
        "name" : "Everybody"
    ]
]

let filteredData = data.filter{
    let string = $0["name"] as! String

    return string.hasPrefix("Goo")
}
```

If you want a contains you just need to do a find in the string.

Again, I'm not lying here. I'm running it in a Playground to check...

For a contains search you can do this...

```
let filteredData = data.filter{
    let string = $0["name"] as! String

    return string.rangeOfString("db") != nil
}
```

[image]

Comment: that's not work for me, because id's are Int =/ And I tried to change type of value to AnyObject, but in that case your func doesn't work =/

Comment: Already...    func filter(array : [[String : AnyObject]], byString filterString : String) -> [[String : AnyObject]] {
        return array.filter{
            dictionary in
            return dictionary["name"] == filterString
        }
    }

Comment: It looks like you're trying to filter whole word, but in my case i need to filter only by a part. Is it ok in your func?

Comment: Do you want the beginning, end or anywhere in the eord? Just update the filter function.

Comment: Same - cannot invoke "filter" with bla-bla.

Comment: Hi, this is work for me. But it is not case sensitive right? I want actually the same result with case sensitive. Please help me.

Comment: @hilaj have you tried it? Why do you think it is not case sensitive?

Comment: Yeah i tried it. But its not getting as case insensitive.

Comment: @hilaj this is case sensitive. What do you actually want? I am confused now as you have suddenly mentioned case “insensitive” which is the opposite. Show an example of what you want. And stop using double negatives.